# Error messages making queryString disapprear in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I have issue from client end with jsf 1.2 as explained below

I am navigating on click on command button to the url below

```
 test/editProject.jsf?value=123
```

If any field are missing I am using addErrorMessage('id','string') and returning fail in validation method. The error message is displayed under that component.. I am fine till this..

The problem is the url is displayed as

```
 test/editProject.jsf
```

Here the **value** queryString is missing..if the user correct the error and click on save it works fine..it is working as per jsf cycle

**Issue**

My client is pressing enter on the browser url tab  which has the url  ***test/editProject.jsf***. I told him to use F5 button to refresh but he didn't agreed.. any idea how to retrieve the query string back on getting error message.

I have used **redirect** in my project but I think here its not good idea to use..

Please let me known if you any solution for this..

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why did you add the `[jsf-2]` tag if you aren't using JSF 2.x?

Comment: sorry BalusC .. I have removed.